# How can i use the result from the first API call as input for the second API call?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have to make multiple API calls in order to get the actual data. I have written the below code to make the first API call. It works but I have to use the return value (let'say it returns access token) from the first call, and use this access token as part of the header on the second API call. How can I achieve that?

```
class Service {
  final String url;
  Map<String, String> header = new Map();
  Map<String, String> body = new Map();

  Service(this.url, this.header, this.body);

  Future<Data> postCall() async {    
    final response = await http.post(url, headers: header, body: body);
    return Data.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
  }
}




class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  Service service;
  Service serviceTwo;
  ....
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: FutureBuilder<Data>(
          future: service.postCall,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return Text(snapshot.data.accessToken);
            } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Text("${snapshot.error}");
           }
          // By default, show a loading spinner.
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        },
      ),
    ),
  ),
);}}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways of achieving that, the simplest one is just using [await](https://dart.dev/tutorials/language/futures#async-await) on your method to append the future calls.

So your method `postCall()` would be something like this:

```dart
Future<Data> postCall() async {
  // The first call, suppose you'll get the token
  final responseToken = await http.post(url, headers: header, body: body);

  // Decode it as you wish
  final token = json.decode(responseToken.body);
  
  // The second call to get data with the token
  final response = await http.get(
    url,
    headers: {authorization: "Bearer $token"},
  );

  // Decode your data and return
  return Data.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
}
```

If it is a token you'll use many times, I recommend you to store it in [flutter_secure_storage](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_secure_storage) and use it as you wish.